# Add SQL conditions to WP_Query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have those SQL conditions that gets events based on whether or not the user is a member of a group.

```
//deal with private groups and events
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    global $wpdb;
    //find out what private groups they belong to, and don't show private group events not in their memberships
    $group_ids = BP_Groups_Member::get_group_ids(get_current_user_id());
    if( $group_ids['total'] > 0){
        $conditions['group_privacy'] = "(`event_private`=0 OR (`event_private`=1 AND (`group_id` IS NULL OR `group_id` = 0)) OR (`event_private`=1 AND `group_id` IN (".implode(',',$group_ids['groups']).")))";
    }else{
        //find out what private groups they belong to, and don't show private group events not in their memberships
        $conditions['group_privacy'] = "(`event_private`=0 OR (`event_private`=1 AND (`group_id` IS NULL OR `group_id` = 0)))";
    } 
}
```

How can I add these conditions to a WP_Query ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: You can't mix WP+Query and SQL, you need to use one or the other. But depending on how that information is  saved to the WP database, you might be able to use `meta_query` in your WP_Query to include the conditions.

Comment: How would that information need to be saved? How can I access the database and see those informations ?

Comment: I've no idea - its your website! How are you adding those values in the first place? ACF? Custom Post? plugin? Check whatever code is adding it for more information.

Comment: It's the Events Manager plugin that adds those information ! And the bit of code I share is what they've pointed me towards. I have to admit I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @FluffyKitten : i've managed to (or tried to) use meta_query and "translate" the SQL query. Since the problem is now different to this, I posted another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381121/translating-sql-query-to-wp-meta-query